# windows batch: react to command not found

Tags: batch-file

i want to write a simple batch script, that calls a certain exe, but if this one is not found, it should call another exe.

so in pseudocode

```
set file=c:\path\tool.exe
if(fileexists(file))
{
    call file
}
else
{
    call c:\somethingelse.exe
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ERRORLEVEL](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) to check if the call executed successfully.

```
call file.exe
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 other.exe
```

This will work for executables that are in the path and you don't know the exact location. It will print an error message though.

Comment: Note that you can also cut that short: `file.exe || other.exe` (and you don't need the `call` there anyway.

Comment: The problem with this, is if file.exe exists, but fails for whatever reason, it will also execute other.exe.  We only want to execute other.exe if file.exe fails due to it not existing.

Answer (score 3):

To closely resemble the pseudo-code posted in the original question:

```
set FILE1=c:\path\tool.exe
set FILE2=c:\path\to\other\tool.exe
if exist "%FILE1%" (
    %FILE1%
) else (
    %FILE2%
)
```

As Joey pointed out this actually is the opened form of:

```
%FILE1% || %FILE2%
```

but I don't agree. The former runs *FILE2*

1. when *FILE1* not exists, or
2. exists but failed.

It also prints an additional error message when a file can't be executed (mostly because it wasn't found or access is prohibited). To suppress this message use:

```
(%FILE1% || %FILE2%) 2>nul
```

For example

```
> (echo a || echo b)
a
> (echoa || echo b) 2>nul
b
```

To suppress all output, and just arrange it that any of both files is run:

```
(%FILE1% || %FILE2%) 1>&2 2>nul
```

or:

```
((%FILE1% || %FILE2%) 1>&2 2>nul) || echo both have failed
```

as in:

```
> ((echo a || echo b) 2>nul) || echo both have failed
a
> ((echoa || echo b) 2>nul) || echo both have failed
b
> ((echoa || echob) 2>nul) || echo both have failed
both have failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this might work?

```
set FILE=whatever.exe
IF EXIST %FILE% GOTO okay

:notokay
echo NOT FOUND
GOTO end

:okay
echo FOUND
%FILE%

:end
```